# My macOS install can not see any WiFi networks. What do I do?

Tags: wifi, macbook

I installed OS 6 Odin today on a 2013 MacBook Pro Retina. When I try to connect to WiFi networks, all I can see are options for VPN and Proxy.

How can I connect to my WiFi network?

in response to matigo:
First, thank you for the help.
Second, my sudo lspci output says I have a "Broadcom BCM4360 801.11ac ... (rev 03)"

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of `sudo lspci`? This will list some of your hardware details. You’ll likely need to configure some Broadcom drivers, and the earlier command will specify which one you need 

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue on a MBP mid-2012 recently - Bluetooth recognised but no WiFi. My adapter is a BCM4331.

Running `dmesg` in the terminal revealed a message suggesting visiting [wireless.wiki.kernel.org](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43) for Broadcom drivers.

That website states your BCM4360 Broadcom WiFi adapter is unsupported, however there is a possible solution involving propietary drivers (covered further down).

### Installing b43

This driver works pretty well, however it doesn't [support 5GHz networks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664094/cant-connect-to-wifi-5ghz-with-broadcom-corporation-bcm4311) and during my usage I found it would drop the connection intermittently.

To install the b43 driver, run the following command in a terminal

```
# apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

and rebooting eOS

### Installing wl

This is the propietary driver available from Broadcom, with full feature support. This hasn't been extensively tested by myself as I've only recently got this working. [Debian's Mac documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple/MacBookPro/9-2) was extremely helpful.

Install your kernel's headers and the propietary driver sources:

```
# apt install linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 && sudo apt install broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source broadcom-sta-dkms
```

*(If you are not running Ubuntu 20.04 or Elementary OS 6, replace the `linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04` package with `linux-headers-$(uname -r)`. Do note that this alternative method requires you to fetch new headers manually when the kernel is updated, otherwise your WiFi will stop working)*

Once installation is complete, unload the old kernel modules for the modem:

```
# modprobe -r b43
# modprobe -r bcma
```

To prevent these modules from reloading on boot, create a new `blacklist-b43.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` with the following contents:

```
blacklist b43
blacklist bcma
```

At this point, you can reboot eOS.

Alternatively you can reload the wl kernel module and start using the WiFi adapter immediately:

```
# modprobe -r wl
# modprobe -r cfg80211
# rfkill unblock
# modprobe wl
```