# Cannot conect WIFI

Tags: wifi

I new get Elementary in my old Windows notebook. Everthing fine untill I tried to conect online. It dosent show me my wifi reds, only can use the notebook with cablet signal.
someone can help me please :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and solved it at this thread.  I hope it helps.

[Installed elementary OS 6 Odin on HP Elitebook 2570p. No WiFi. Broadcom BCM43228](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/29019/installed-elementary-os-6-odin-on-hp-elitebook-2570p-no-wifi-broadcom-bcm43228/29030#29030)