# no internet connection on fresh elementary os install

Tags: wifi, drivers

after some time on pop os I recently install elementary os and i can't connect to my network, i haven't done any update. the option won't even show in the settings. I had the same problem on pop os thats why i change but its still not working i have no idea how to fix it

> *-network
> description : Network controller
> product: Wi-fi 6 AX200
> vendor: Intel Corporation

Answer (score 0):

Read this thread here.  It may be applicable to your situation.

[Installed elementary OS 6 Odin on HP Elitebook 2570p. No WiFi. Broadcom BCM43228](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/29019/installed-elementary-os-6-odin-on-hp-elitebook-2570p-no-wifi-broadcom-bcm43228/29030#29030)